# How to plot different months as different series in the same graph in R

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, levels

I have the following dataset

```
head(Data)
    Fecha PriceStats
1 01-2002    45.2071
2 02-2002    46.6268
3 03-2002    48.4712
4 04-2002    53.5067
5 05-2002    55.6527
6 06-2002    57.6684
```

There´s a total of 176 observations.

Every row corresponds to a different month.

I would like to create a graph with the 12 months of the year in the x-axis and that every year of the dataset (containing 12 months each) corresponds to a series in the graph so I can plot all the different years overlapping (in these case would be 15 series).

Do I have to set levels on the dataset or ggplot can do that directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

Data <- data.frame(date = seq(ymd('2014/01/01'), ymd('2016/12/01'), 30), 
                       n = sample(1:50, 36))

Data$month <- month(Data$date)
Data$year <- year(Data$date)

ggplot(Data, aes(x = month, y = n, group = year)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour = as.factor(year)))
```

Comment: This assumes that your 'Fecha' column is already in date format. Otherwise you will have to convert it. One quick way (but probably not the best) using lubridate would be: Data$Fecha <- dmy(paste('1-', Data$Fecha, sep = ''))